# Coherence :Issue while evicting key from a cache using Entry Processor

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I am trying to evict cache key using `EvictProcessor`, Does anybody know what this error means? I am getting this error with `Coherence 3.7` while this code was working with `Coherence 3.5`.

**Error:**
`The internal map of a ReadWriteBackingMap has an unexpected EvictionApprover; custom maps should accept and use the supplied approver`

```
public class EvictProcessor extends AbstractProcessor implements
    ExternalizableLite, PortableObject {

static ValueExtractor s_extractorMap = new ReflectionExtractor("getMap");
static ValueExtractor s_extractorKey = new ReflectionExtractor("getBinaryKey");

public EvictProcessor() {
}

public Object process(com.tangosol.util.InvocableMap.Entry entry) {
    if (entry.isPresent())
    {
        final ReadWriteBackingMap bm = (ReadWriteBackingMap) s_extractorMap.extract(entry); 
        final ConfigurableCacheMap local = (ConfigurableCacheMap) bm.getInternalCache(); 
        local.evict(s_extractorKey.extract(entry));
    }
    return null 
}
public void readExternal(PofReader pofreader) throws IOException {}
public void writeExternal(PofWriter pofwriter) throws IOException {}
}
```

And then I am using above `EvictProcessor` to evict the entries from cache.

```
cache.invoke(key,new EvictProcessor ());
```

When I upgraded Coherence to `3.7.1.16` above error disappeared but still eviction not working.

Comment: see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22623/technotes.htm#BABGCGDD. There is an info about fixed bug with `EvictionApprover`. Maybe you should upgrade Coherence version.

Comment: @KrzysztofKosmatka When I upgraded to Coherence 3.7.1.16 this error message disappeared but Manual Eviction is still not working.

Comment: What is the actual class of `entry`? Does it have methods `getMap` and `getBinaryKey`? Does `process` method ends without exception? I didn't search thoroughly, but I don't see `getMap` method on any common `InvocableMap.Entry` implementations. Maybe between 3.5 and 3.7 implementation of `InvocableMap.Entry` has been changed or `getMap` method has been removed. I'm just guessing here, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: @KrzysztofKosmatka After upgrading to 3.7.1.16 eviction is still not working for few distributed caches. I don see any error or warning.

Comment: I'm affraid I cannot help you any further.

Comment: I'm just curious why are you using reflection and trying to access Coherence internals, which, as you can see, can change from version to version? Is there anything wrong with calling `InvocableMap.Entry#remove`?

Comment: @SergeyKhudyakov As part of manual eviction we just want to evict entries from Local Cache of backing map. Problem is this eviction is very random. When I debug the code I can see entry is getting evicted everytime but again it is getting added. I also applied listener on backing map cache where I can see one delete event first time while in other attempt I see two events of Add and delete.

Comment: @SergeyKhudyakov calling InvocableMap.Entry@remove will call its erase method of cache store which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

There was bug in Coherence `v3.7.1.16` with eviction using `BackingMap`. This issue got fixed when upgraded to `Coherence v12`.